# How can I use image overlay correctly with Bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap and CSS to design my page, and I was able to do some image overlay effect. But I'm not able to keep my original layout and the overlay image does not fit 100% to the image, even though the width is set to 100%. I was not able to find out the image overlay function(?) on bootstrap documentation. Is there a way to use CSS to apply the overlay effect without bothering my bootstrap layout? Below is my code.

```css
.images img {
    width: 400px;
    padding: 10px;
}

.col {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}

.overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: .5s ease;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
}

.col:hover .overlay {
    opacity: 0.6;
}
```

```html
<style>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
</style>


<div class="d-flex justify-content-center images">
    <div class="col">
      <a href="#"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="d"></a>
        <div class="overlay">
            <div class="text">Oct 30, 2020</div>
        </div>
    </div>
      <a href="#"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="d"></a>
      <a href="#"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="d"></a>
</div>
```

Comment: My first advice is to not override core Bootstrap classes with custom CSS. Use the grid for layout and apply your custom styles to the contents of that grid. (Don't re-style `.col`.)

Comment: Then, I typically wouldn't use columns without rows and a container. Use flex or use columns, not both. I could be wrong, but that seems like an odd combination.

Comment: Then, a question: Why do you have a fixed image width in what's presumably supposed to be a fluid layout? Are you trying to keep a minimum size?

Comment: So I had a lot of a hard time getting my images correct, and finally, after many days of trial, this was the best I could do. And now I want to apply the effect, it just messes up my bootstrap layout.......  And without a fixed image width, the image gets too large.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what the overall layout goal is, but doing a couple things seems to help:

1. Reset the display mode of `.overlay` to `block` (from `flex`)
2. Take the fixed width off your images

```css
.images img {
    padding: 10px;
}

.col {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}

.overlay {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: .5s ease;
    background-color: pink;
}

.col:hover .overlay {
    opacity: 0.6;
}
```

```html
<style>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
</style>


<div class="d-flex justify-content-center images">
    <div class="col">
      <a href="#"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="d"></a>
        <div class="overlay">
            <div class="text">Oct 30, 2020</div>
        </div>
    </div>
      <a href="#"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="d"></a>
      <a href="#"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="d"></a>
</div>
```